# Backward Euler without fixed-point iteration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I'm having some confusion on the correct implementation of the Backward Euler method. Assume we have a general 1st order ODE given in the form:

$$ \frac{dy(t)}{dt} = f(y(t),t) $$

Typically I recall it is implicit, meaning we expect a given step to be calculated from: $$y_{n+1} = y_n + f(y_{n+1},t_{n+1})  \, \delta y$$

However, in implementing Forward Euler and Backward Euler side-by-side, it seems like I can, given initial conditions $y_0$ (and $y_1$ for BE), choose to approximate the derivative with either a forward step or a backward step. write these as:

$$ FE: \qquad y_{n+1} = y_{n} + \left[ \frac{y(t+\delta t) \,-\,y(t)}{\delta t}\right] \delta t$$

$$ BE: \qquad y_{n+1} = y_{n} + \left[ \frac{y(t) \,-\,y(t-\delta t)}{\delta t}\right] \delta t$$

Where we Taylor expand the terms in the brackets to first order. This seems to allow us to have a simple explicit scheme using either a forward or backward difference approximation, but seems not to line up with the expected format.

My question then is - is this Backward Euler? If not, what have I done and what is wrong with it? (It seems to work well enough). And how would I change this to get to an implicit scheme (which I believe would need the solution of a fixed-point problem at every iteration step).

Perhaps I am getting confused with applying the concept to different use-cases, if Euler methods are used differently when not solving 1st order ODEs. (Indeed - are they used at all for other purposes or are they purely for integrating ODEs?)

Comment: Your last two equations are not correct, assuming that $y(t)$ is an exact solution then the difference of both sides is the local truncation error of size $O(δt^2)$.

Comment: Apologies - that's sloppy notation; these are finite difference approximations so not equalities. Strictly I meant them as pseudocode - $y_{n+1}$ is calculated from the RHS where the square brackets contain the derivative. However I think I see I've tried to 'wash one hand with the other' by showing derivative  approximations... Since I believe that both methods require an analytical derivative f(y,t) to work, the square brackets are not applicable here. But then what is the meaning/point of the two approaches to approximating a derivative, if they're not required for solving the ODE?

Comment: The point is stability. If you have some components that go to zero or some other limit, the explicit method may overshoot, sometimes into "physically" impossible regions, while the implicit method gives results that do not that blatantly violate basic properties of the system, like the positivity of variables. If you simulate a star cluster with explicit Euler, the simulation tends to explode, while with implicit Euler it "only" collapses to a single point. See the "Moving stars around" project for illustration and code examples.